# How to integrate HTTP Digest Auth into Strongloop's Loopback?

Tags: authentication, passport.js, loopback, http-digest

I'm relatively new to Strongloop's Loopback.

A project I'm working on requires [HTTP-Digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) to use as authentication.

I have setup the ACL on the models (and endpoints). SPA client uses REST to consume services.

I'm stuck on how to use http digest auth (username:realm:password) / nonce instead of the plain login of username/password.

I still would like to use the token auth also.

I'm currently looking at the ff 3 projects though:

- [loopback-component-auth](https://github.com/benkroeger/loopback-component-auth)
- [passport-http](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http)
- [loopback-component-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport)

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Express Middleware to configure HTTP authentication:

Use this node module: http-auth

Create digest-auth.js boot script in server/boot folder

```
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "<your authentication realm>",
    file: __dirname + "<path to your .htpasswd file"
});

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(auth.connect(basic));

    // Setup route. 
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.send("Secured resource access granted!");
    });
}
```

You can check more option available with "http-auth" module to use "username:realm:password" for authentication

Hope this would help you !